# display a gravity form according the ID filled in a custom field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, gravity-forms-plugin

I really like the way your community in help us guys.

i have a CPT with ACF field on back end, and I want to display a specific gravity form on front end. On back end, I created a custom field named "gravity form". ([see pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKQzc.jpg)) The webmaster will fill in the field the ID of the gravity form that he wants to display on front end in the page. so I wrote a [line of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6eqy.png).

```
<!-- Gravity form -->
<?php 
$gnumber = get_field('gf_id');
gravity_form ("<?php echo $gnumber ; ?>", true, true, false, false, true, false, true );
?>
```

Actually if I write

```
<?php gravity_form (303, true, true, false, false, true, false, true );?>
```

It will display the form with the ID 303.

But in my case I want to display whatever ID they will fill in, so I thought by replacing the ID by the Echo $.. it will work but it doesn't.

I have spent so much time looking for it.
Can you help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we can start from the top:

Assuming you are placing this code in your template file:

1. put `<?php the_field('gf_id') ?>` somewhere in your HTML to see if there's an output

If it does, it means that your ACF field is retrieved from the CPT according to the post type and ID, move on to 2)

If it doesn't, take a look here [How to get post ID - Wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) and [How to use get_field with post ID - ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/)

2. do a raw echo of $gnumber on your theme file to see if there's any output
3. when 1) and 2) is working, ensure your gravity_form() method has the correct parameters passed [How to use gravity form in theme - Gravity Forms](https://docs.gravityforms.com/adding-a-form-to-the-theme-file/)

From what I can see, your `<?php` and `?>` are not opened and closed properly

```
<!-- Gravity form -->
<?php 
$gnumber = get_field('gf_id');
gravity_form ("<?php echo $gnumber ; ?>", true, true, false, false, true, false, true );
?>
```

should be

```
<!-- Gravity form -->
<?php 
$gnumber = get_field('gf_id');
gravity_form ($gnumber, true, true, false, false, true, false, true );
?>
```

Comment: You are the best, thank you so much.

Comment: actually the gravity_form ($gnumber, .......) works perfectly. (no need to put an echo $gnumber)